# How to nuke all Ruby Gems from the system and start over

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

What's the easiest way to start over with Ruby Gems? I have Ruby 1.8.7 (OSX, ports) installed and I have also installed rails and some other random stuff a while back. Now the gems system seems to be totally dysfunctional and I can't upgrade rails. So is there a way to just nuke the gems so I can reinstall all this stuff with current versions?

Comment: Do yourself a favour and have a look at RVM: http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/

Comment: Looks like a useful tool, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wipe your current gems from GEM PATH directory (you can check it via `$ gem env`). Then run `$ which -a gem` to nuke the bin files. After that - reinstall rubygems from the source and enjoy your new rubygems life.